# How do we start implementing HipHop for our web servers?

Tags: php, facebook, hiphop

I want to use [HipHop](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/) but I've got no idea how do I go about doing that. Does anyone know of any tutorials that teach us how to implement HipHop for our websites?

Is there alot of configuration to do or is it more like sort of a change a config file and everything just works sort of thing?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there are several examples in the documentation:

https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/Running-HipHop